# json.loads error when proccessing request.content

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Running this code I get the error: **Extra data: line 1 column 12 (char 11)**

```
url = "https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/?format=text/csv&zipCode=19020&date=2020-10-05&distance=25&API_KEY=......"

try:
    api_request = requests.get(url)
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

this is the output of **print(api_request.content)** I do not see anything strange in column 12.
What am I missing here?

b'"DateIssue","DateForecast","ReportingArea","StateCode","Latitude","Longitude","ParameterName","AQI","CategoryNumber","CategoryName","ActionDay","Discussion"\n"2020-10-02 ","2020-10-05 ","Philadelphia","PA","39.95","-75.151","PM2.5","48","1","Good","false","Current conditions: The sun has broken through the clouds this Friday afternoon. With a cool and clean air mass in place, fine particulate is down inside the good range. Tonight will turn out mostly moonlit and chilly as temperatures fall back to the middle 40s away from urban areas.  ***  Saturday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Sunshine for the most part Saturday with temperatures only recovering into the middle and upper 60s. Enough dry air will remain present to where particles remain in the good range.  ***  Sunday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Sunday will continue with sunshine most of the day, but a few clouds may show up towards evening. With less mixing and lighter winds, there is the chance for low moderate particle levels in parts of the area.  ***   Monday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Showers will occur Sunday night into Monday morning, then perhaps a little sun is possible late in the day. If there is enough afternoon mixing, fine particulate concentrations may retreat to the upper good range.  ***  Extended forecast: Milder air will be transported in on southwesterly winds Tuesday into Wednesday. The next cold front will then move through Wednesday night, and bring another cooldown behind it later on in the week. Moderate air quality is again a possibility Tuesday, otherwise PM2.5 levels will be low most of the remainder of the week.---McAuliffe "\n"2020-10-02 ","2020-10-06 ","Philadelphia","PA","39.95","-75.151","PM2.5","53","2","Moderate","false","Current conditions: The sun has broken through the clouds this Friday afternoon. With a cool and clean air mass in place, fine particulate is down inside the good range. Tonight will turn out mostly moonlit and chilly as temperatures fall back to the middle 40s away from urban areas.  ***  Saturday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Sunshine for the most part Saturday with temperatures only recovering into the middle and upper 60s. Enough dry air will remain present to where particles remain in the good range.  ***  Sunday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Sunday will continue with sunshine most of the day, but a few clouds may show up towards evening. With less mixing and lighter winds, there is the chance for low moderate particle levels in parts of the area.  ***   Monday\xe2\x80\x99s forecast: Showers will occur Sunday night into Monday morning, then perhaps a little sun is possible late in the day. If there is enough afternoon mixing, fine particulate concentrations may retreat to the upper good range.  ***  Extended forecast: Milder air will be transported in on southwesterly winds Tuesday into Wednesday. The next cold front will then move through Wednesday night, and bring another cooldown behind it later on in the week. Moderate air quality is again a possibility Tuesday, otherwise PM2.5 levels will be low most of the remainder of the week.---McAuliffe "\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url has parameter `format=text/csv`. you want `format=json`

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/?format=json&zipCode=19020&date=2020-10-05&distance=25&API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY"


api_request = requests.get(url)
json_data = api_request.json() # beter use the convenient method of Response object
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)) # this is just to show the response
```

output

```
[
    {
        "DateIssue": "2020-10-02 ",
        "DateForecast": "2020-10-05 ",
        "ReportingArea": "Philadelphia",
        "StateCode": "PA",
        "Latitude": 39.95,
        "Longitude": -75.151,
        "ParameterName": "PM2.5",
        "AQI": 48,
        "Category": {
            "Number": 1,
            "Name": "Good"
        },
        "ActionDay": false,
        "Discussion": "Current conditions: The sun has broken through the clouds this Friday afternoon. With a cool and clean air mass in place, fine particulate is down inside the good range. Tonight will turn out mostly moonlit and chilly as temperatures fall back to the middle 40s away from urban areas.  ***  Saturday\u2019s forecast: Sunshine for the most part Saturday with temperatures only recovering into the middle and upper 60s. Enough dry air will remain present to where particles remain in the good range.  ***  Sunday\u2019s forecast: Sunday will continue with sunshine most of the day, but a few clouds may show up towards evening. With less mixing and lighter winds, there is the chance for low moderate particle levels in parts of the area.  ***   Monday\u2019s forecast: Showers will occur Sunday night into Monday morning, then perhaps a little sun is possible late in the day. If there is enough afternoon mixing, fine particulate concentrations may retreat to the upper good range.  ***  Extended forecast: Milder air will be transported in on southwesterly winds Tuesday into Wednesday. The next cold front will then move through Wednesday night, and bring another cooldown behind it later on in the week. Moderate air quality is again a possibility Tuesday, otherwise PM2.5 levels will be low most of the remainder of the week.---McAuliffe "
    },
    {
        "DateIssue": "2020-10-02 ",
        "DateForecast": "2020-10-06 ",
        "ReportingArea": "Philadelphia",
        "StateCode": "PA",
        "Latitude": 39.95,
        "Longitude": -75.151,
        "ParameterName": "PM2.5",
        "AQI": 53,
        "Category": {
            "Number": 2,
            "Name": "Moderate"
        },
        "ActionDay": false,
        "Discussion": "Current conditions: The sun has broken through the clouds this Friday afternoon. With a cool and clean air mass in place, fine particulate is down inside the good range. Tonight will turn out mostly moonlit and chilly as temperatures fall back to the middle 40s away from urban areas.  ***  Saturday\u2019s forecast: Sunshine for the most part Saturday with temperatures only recovering into the middle and upper 60s. Enough dry air will remain present to where particles remain in the good range.  ***  Sunday\u2019s forecast: Sunday will continue with sunshine most of the day, but a few clouds may show up towards evening. With less mixing and lighter winds, there is the chance for low moderate particle levels in parts of the area.  ***   Monday\u2019s forecast: Showers will occur Sunday night into Monday morning, then perhaps a little sun is possible late in the day. If there is enough afternoon mixing, fine particulate concentrations may retreat to the upper good range.  ***  Extended forecast: Milder air will be transported in on southwesterly winds Tuesday into Wednesday. The next cold front will then move through Wednesday night, and bring another cooldown behind it later on in the week. Moderate air quality is again a possibility Tuesday, otherwise PM2.5 levels will be low most of the remainder of the week.---McAuliffe "
    }
]
```

I replaced your API KEY. You should not post it.

EDIT: Here is refactored version, which in my opinion is better/more clear

```
import requests
import json

API_KEY = 'YOUR-API-KEY'
payload = {'format':'json',
           'zipCode':'19020',
           'date':'2020-10-05',
           'distance':'25',
           'API_KEY':API_KEY}

url = "https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/"

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
json_data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)) # this is just to show the response
```

Comment: Thank you for the API KEY reminder. When I try to run your code I get the same error. I am using python 3.8 on windows 10. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 12 (char 11)

Comment: My code runs - I show you the output. I just removed the API key here. Make sure you updated and saved the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting a `csv` response

Try:

```
import csv
    
url = "https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/?format=text/csv&zipCode=19020&date=2020-10-05&distance=25&API_KEY=363DB50B-2501-4390-863A-1E138CC1923F"
try:
    api_request = requests.get(url)
    api = csv.reader(api_request.content)
    for row in api:
        print(row)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```